# jackrabbit editing repository files using webdav

Tags: java, tomcat, webdav, jackrabbit

I have deployed **jackrabbit2.6.3.war** in **tomcat7.0**.

By using **jackrabbit standalone jar** . Written a program to save a file in repository

I can save/push a file to jackrabbit default repository.
If I'm trying to save/push the same file,It is creating a new version of the same file.

***Now My Question is*** I want to edit these files by using webdav . I have changed IE settings and am able to open in **read-only** mode. I want to open in **read-write** mode.

***Another Question :*** Even if I open a file in read-write mode and change something in it , will jackrabbit create new version of the file OR will the file get overridden?

But according to JCR regulation,one file cannot overrite the existing file,always create a new version of it.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

1/ IE is not a webdav client, you have to use 'web folders' network neighborhood to 'mount' the repository.

2/ That depends on your configuration, if you want a versionned node or not. I don't know which JCR regulations you are referring to.

Comment: If we opening a document in editable mode using webdav.For this we need to change some IE setting(I use to do before) .

**1)** can you please give me some more details on **web folder** integration with jackrabbit to make a document editable.

**2)** we cannot override the same file which is already exists in jackrabbit repository. this is how jackrabbit behaves .

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know but at Silverpeas they are using it to edit document in Ms Office or Open/Libre Office via webdav directly and the document is updated. 
If I 'mount' the directory I can add files, folders etc (provided I have the rights to do so of course).

For Windows Explorer configuration take a look at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/windows-7-webdav-web-folders-support-for-64bit/a48a13a3-b9c4-4d4f-a3cd-47ce9e52d7a9 for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to open in read/write mode using some Filter code from net.java.dev.webdav.webdav-interop

I have been using maven to compile the checked out webdav-interop svn sources into my local repository.

adding the following to my pom.xml in jackrabbit-webapp 
builds the jackrabbit-webapp with the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.webdav</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdav-interop</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

you might need to change the webdav-interop code a bit in order to cover the index.jsp of the jackrabbit-webapp

```
            final boolean isRoot = (uri.equals(ROOT_RESOURCE) || uri.equals(ROOT_RESOURCE+"index.jsp")) ;
```